# How to use Select tags in Laravel Forms

Tags: php, laravel

For some reason the value is not outputting when I press submit. There is always an error it basically says there is no data.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="">
        <label for="category">Size</label>
        <br>
        <select name="category" class="form-control">
            @foreach($size as $s)
            <option value="{{ $s->id }}">{{ $s->size }}</option>
            @endforeach
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What's your full form?

Comment: Show me the error and your PHP code.

Answer (score 0):

just using pluck and map into Form select

in your controller

```
$model = Model::pluck('size', 'id')->toArray();
return view('view', compact('model'))
```

in view

```
{{ Form::select('category', $model, null, ['class' => 'form-control']) }}
```